# Firebase & Flutter: check if value exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

this is my very first stackoverflow question :D

I am currently trying to build a shopping list app in Flutter. I use firebase as database.

You can add ingredients to the list "Items", these get beside the cryptic key some attributes like "Name" and "Quantity".
Now I want to make the app so that if "Milk" is already on the shopping list, and then I want to add "Milk" again, the "Number" of milk is increased by one. Currently, "Milk" is then simply on the list twice.

The structure of the database is as follows:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDu6e.png)

I am grateful for any tips.
Cheers

Comment: You can use Firebase query for this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: But does it work with a realtime database, or only with firestore?

Comment: check this: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage/

Comment: Hello what have you tried?? Your question is very broad and therefore it is difficult to answer without knowing your current code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.